# mysql DATETIME BETWEEN query not working as expected

Tags: mysql

I have following data which clearly showing data available between date used in query
[image]

My query

```
SELECT * FROM dashboard WHERE added BETWEEN "2018-05-08 10:32:32" AND "2018-05-08 10:28:30"
```

but This query returning empty row set. What going wrong. I have exported this table from production server & imported in development server. `added`field is `DATETIME`. Please help

Comment: Some manual reading would be useful expr BETWEEN min AND max (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first boundary must be lower than the second.

Try reversing the comparison values. E.g

```
SELECT * FROM dashboard 
WHERE added BETWEEN "2018-05-08 10:28:30" 
      AND "2018-05-08 10:32:32"
```

The reason behind this is due to the fact that the first value is compared using >=  then the second value compared using <= thus the second value must be greater than the first or nothing is returned.

Answer (score 1):

the clause: `BETWEEN "2018-05-08 10:32:32" AND "2018-05-08 10:28:30"` is correctly returning an empty set since from is after until. Did you mean:

```
BETWEEN   "2018-05-08 10:28:30" AND "2018-05-08 10:32:32"
```